# Boolean doesn't take away the part it's supposed to only

Tags: boolean-modifier

I've been wanting to make a boolean into a road 3d model I made with a UV sphere but it doesn't work as intended. Instead of removing the parts its clipping with, it takes away all of the road except for a few imperfections I added.[image: Before Boolean] [image: After Boolean]

Comment: Hello and welcome! booleans are tricky and it takes some experience to understand what will work and what won't and what workarounds to take. They are also sometimes buggy and create undesired unclean geometry so I would stay away from them unless absolutely necessary and impossible to model without. But from what you have presented it is unclear what exactly you are trying to do. Maybe try providing more details or drawing a sketch.

Comment: I think it would help to share a minimal .blend  file that exposes the problem on https://blend-exchange.com/ . There are quite a few reasons this could happen.

Comment: Here's the [link](https://filebin.net/m098s6i1qt2o4op7) to the .blend file. I added a few extra things but that shouldn't be an issue.